# Get Accumulo instance name

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, accumulo, geomesa

I want to use GeoMesa (GIS extension of Accumulo) and virtualized it using Docker just like [this repo](https://github.com/rheilgm/testgeo). Now I want to connect to the Accumulo instance using Java using:

```
 Instance i = new ZooKeeperInstance("docker_instance",zkIP:port);
 Connector conn = i.getConnector(user, new PasswordToken(password));
```

The connetion does not get established and hangs (just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505166/connecting-an-external-accumulo-instance-and-java)). I can connect to the ZooKeeper instance using using

```
./zkCli.sh -server ip:port
```

So i guess the instance_name is wrong. I used the one noted in the repo linked first. However I don't know where how to check the instance_name needed.

---

To make my problem reproducable I did [setup a digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-big-data-friendly-apache-accumulo-nosql-database-on-ubuntu-14-04) server with all necessary dependencies and accumulo. I tested that the connection to zookeeper is possible using zkCli and checked the credentials using `accumulo shell` on the server.

```
 Instance i = new ZooKeeperInstance("DIGITAL_OCEAN","46.101.199.216:2181");
 // WARN  org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ClientConfiguration  - Found no client.conf in default paths. Using default client configuration values.
 System.out.println("This is reached");
 Connector conn = i.getConnector("root", new PasswordToken("mypassw"));
 System.out.println("This is not reached");
```

Comment: The Accumulo instance name is the name you provided when running `accumulo init`. You can see this name on the Accumulo Monitor.

You also didn't provide any information about the actual error (is it hanging on the first line of code or the second?). Do you see an error eventually? Have you got a thread dump from the process when it is stuck? Have you increased the log4j debug level?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the location of the instance_name - sadly I used the correct one. Regarding the problem: It hangs at the second command, but it also displays a warning when creating the ZooKeeperInstance: `[main] WARN  org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ClientConfiguration  - Found no client.conf in default paths. Using default client configuration values.`

Comment: That's actually coming from the ClientConfiguration object which ZKI is implicitly creating for you. You can get rid of that by using the ZKI constructor which accepts a ClientConfiguration object (and set the instanceName and zookeepers string on that object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a troubleshooting step, you may be able to extract the instance name by using `HdfsZooInstance.getInstance().getInstanceName()` or by connecting directly to ZooKeeper and listing the instance names with `ls /accumulo/instances/`

Comment: Connecting to zookeeper and using `ls /accumulo/instances /` works. Sadly it is the instance_name I expected it to be, so there must be another problem with my connection

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple easy ways to get the instance_name: Ether just **look to the top of the accumulo status page** as elserj noted in the comments or use zkCli to connect to Zookeeper and use **`ls /accumulo/instances /`** as Christopher answered.

However I could not manage to connect to accumulo using the ordinary Java Connector. Nevertheless I managed to connect to Accumulo using the **[Proxy-Settings](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/tree/master/proxy)** which is a valid solution for me, even that I still would have liked to find the problem.